# What do you call a show that last 2 seasons?

Tags: word-request

> Instead of lasting only 1 season, they should have made the show into
>   a two-season show.

Let's say the year is divided into 4 seasons: fall, winter, spring, summer. What would you call a TV show whose span last 2 entire seasons? I thought about "two-season", but it sounds a bit off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *season* for a TV show isn't the same as the *seasons* of a year. Most TV shows that have seasons have one season per year, lasting anything from 6 to 24 episodes at 1 episode a week (countries have different trends on season length).

There's no natural expression for the meaning you're asking for. In your example, the natural second half of the sentence might be "they should have **made a second season**".